# I have an error in your SQL syntax while updating?

Tags: mysql, sql

So this is my table

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+------+
| I_Code | Name         | Category     | rate |
+--------+--------------+--------------+------+
|   1001 | Masala Dosa  | South Indian |   60 |
|   1002 | Vada Sambhar | South Indian |   40 |
|   1003 | Idli         | South Indian |   40 |
|   1004 | Chow Mein    | Chinese      |   80 |
|   2002 | Dimsum       | Chinese      |   60 |
+--------+--------------+--------------+------+
```

and I_Code is the primary key. I want to change the I_Code of Chow Mein to 2001 and I'm using the following code

```
use food;
update table items
set I_Code = 2001
where name = "Chow Mein";
```

But it keeps giving this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table items set I_Code = 2001 where name = "Chow Mein"' at line 1
```

What's going wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement does not require (nor is it proper syntax to include) a `TABLE` token; your statement should be more in the form of`UPDATE <table_name> SET <field>=<value> WHERE <condition>`. Can you share a source upon which you’re basing your implicit claim to the contrary?

Answer (score 0):

`Table` keyword isn't used after the `update` keyword. The tablename is used after the keyword `update`.

eg.

```
update items set I_Code = 2001 where name = "Chow Mein";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're syntax is wrong!
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

This should work:

```
update items
set I_Code = 2001
where name = "Chow Mein";
```

"update table (tablename)" is not the syntaxt it's just "update (tablename)"

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following syntax:**

```
UPDATE table_name SET col-name = value WHERE id = value
```

**Your Answer :**

```
UPDATE items SET I_Code = 2001 WHERE Name = 'Chow Mein';
```

**if this not works , then try this :**

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE items SET I_Code = 2001 WHERE Name = 'Chow Mein';
```